# Should I create primary key on a temporary table in a stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, database, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that needs to create dynamically 3 temp tables and join them in a large query that includes other tables.

Is it good practice to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It actually depends, it is not a good or bad practice. If it is about performance, you don't actually need the PK, what you need is a clustered index (that is created by default on SQL Server when you create the PK). In any case, it is important that if you are doing a bulk insert of the temp tables, you first load the table, and then create the index. If you create the index and then insert the data, the index might get fragmented.

Personally, I would monitor the process with and without indexes and choose the best option. Sometimes, creating the index takes more time than doing the table scan. But if the tables are big, it might actually be a lot better to create the index and then do whatever transformation you need to do.

Comment: In my experience, I just want to emphasize what you've said: Load the temp table, and THEN add whatever indexes you might need. In literally every test I've done, this is faster than creating a temp table with indexes and then loading the data. And you can really tell if you need an index by looking at the plan... run the procedure with sample data and the "show actual plan" option on, and you can readily see the issues and if indexing fixes them.

Comment: @asemprini87 you are right ,I checked the query plan and It does make a difference when you add the pk, it all depends on how much data are you going to manipulate in your temp table.